# How to create ubuntu server in ubuntu 18.04 operting system?

Tags: command-line, server, docker, development, jenkins

I want to install the docker for learning purposes.But most tutorials mention that we have to use the Ubuntu server for that.Currently I am using the Ubuntu 18.04 OS.How can I create the Ubuntu server in the Ubuntu 18.04 OS.

Comment: Weird question. A working system = kernel + server + desktop. Those are 3 separate components The 1st makes it Linux. Then 2nd a server edition. The 3rd makes it a specific flavour.  So you do not create a server from Ubuntu 18.04. You already have that installed. You can run docker from ANY Ubuntu.

Comment: Please apologize if i made any mistake.If it is possible please recommend a standard resource for docker installing.Trying with so many tutorials Now I do not have clear idea about this.

Comment: You could follow the [official docker tutorial](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/) for installing. Or you can install the [snap version](https://snapcraft.io/docker). Or you could install the version of docker that is [bundled with Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/docker.io). These go from latest to oldest versions.

Comment: @ArturMeinild hmmm you could have it that an answer ;-)  Please use the 2nd link; it is a one-liner.